# What differences exist between valign and vertical-align?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, valign

Is there any difference at all between having a td with the attribute valign set and having the same TD with the style set to the equivalent "vertical-align"?

I see lots of people saying to switch over, but nobody explicitly saying they are 100% compatible or pointing out the differences.

Comment: HTML and CSS evolved and attributes that style elements are no more used and should be replaced with CSS. So you will find a lot of equivalent values BUT you should no more style elements using attribute

Comment: @TemaniAfif: that doesn’t help me determine what, if anything, breaks, when I switch from one to the other.

Comment: That's not really the issue. You are *obliged* to switch whether it breaks something or not. If it's the case, you need to fix what is broken

Answer (score 1):

The [deprecated](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_td_valign) and obsolete [`valign` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-valign) applies only to table cells and offers these value options:

- baseline
- bottom
- middle
- top

By contrast, the [`vertical-align` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) applies to most inline, inline-block, and table-cell elements, and offers several additional options:

- sub
- super
- text-top
- text-bottom
- arbitrary length and percentage values

Otherwise I'd expect them to be essentially interchangeable.

```css
.vertical-align-top {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.vertical-align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.vertical-align-baseline {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

td {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">valign</td>
    <td class="vertical-align-top">vertical-align top</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="middle">valign middle</td>
    <td class="vertical-align-middle">vertical-align middle</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td valign="baseline">valign baseline</td>
    <td class="vertical-align-baseline">vertical-align baseline</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```